# How to get a "constructor" or a factory without reflection in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

As Flutter has no reflection (due to tree shaking) I need to find a way to create Objects of a specific Type at runtime and I would strongly prefere to do it without code generation. So I think the best way to register a Type to be created like this would be the following:

```
class Test with Bindable {
  static Test create() {
    return new Test();
  }
}

registerTest() {
  registerType<Test>("test", Test.create);
}

void registerType<T extends Bindable>(String s, T Function() create) {}
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why do you refuse code generation?

Comment: Because it is tedious and adds its own set of boiler plate code. Code generation will probably add more boiler plate then needing to add a static pseudo constructor to every class

Comment: was looking for something similar few days back. have to say your solution looks good to me. I honestly gave up.